# Why does filtering data in Django break my code?

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

I've got a rather strange problem - which is caused by the following line of code:

```
userlist = twitter_user.objects.filter(enabled=True)
```

If I comment out this line, the code works fine, however when uncomment it, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 33, in <module>
    userlist = twitter_user.objects.filter(enabled=True) ###This is the line that causes the trouble.
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 141, in filter
    return self.get_query_set().filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 561, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 579, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1170, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1058, in add_filter
    negate=negate, process_extras=process_extras)
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1225, in setup_joins
    field, model, direct, m2m = opts.get_field_by_name(name)
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 296, in get_field_by_name
    cache = self.init_name_map()
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 326, in init_name_map
    for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 401, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
    cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 415, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
    for klass in get_models():
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 167, in get_models
    self._populate()
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 76, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/home/beano/projects/bikernod.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named tweetgrab
```

I thought it may be something to do with the model itself, so I've tried changing from a models.BooleanField() to models.CharField() - This makes no difference.

Here is the models.py entry from the tweetgrab application:

```
from django.db import models

class twitter_user(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    enabled = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

From what I can make out (I'm quite new to Django/Python), the line of code I stated initially is causing the application not to be found.

I've also made sure its included in the settings.py file - in installed apps as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'tweetgrab',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
     'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Any idea whats going on here, I've also tried this with both MySQL and Sqlite - the same thing happens with both.

Comment: tweetgrab isn't on your python path

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason django is having trouble importing `tweetgrab`.

I would suggest 2 things (assuming `tweetgrab` is an app inside your project):

1. Make sure the parent directory of your project is on your python path.
2. Start importing apps / set them in `INSTALLED_APPS` as `myproject.app`. That way you won't run into strange issues where `import local_file` works but doesn't from outside that scope.

On a side note, I highly recommend following the naming convention of class names being Capitalized as it will help others and yourself distinguish at a glance what are classes vs functions.